# diagonalize a non-normal matrix , without distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I wonder how to diagonalize a matrix that is non-normal, and does not have distinct eigenvalues.

Let  $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalue, and $v_i$ be the eigenvector with that eigenvalue.

I think the process would go like this:

1. Determine if $\dim(\mathrm{span}(v_i)) = $ multiplicity of $\lambda_i$. If no, then it is not diagonolizable. If yes, go to 2
2. Is the eigenvectors linearly independent? If yes, we can diagonalize. If no, ... I don't know.

Comment: Eigenvectors relative to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-normal matrices may or may not be diagonalizable.

Given $n\in \mathbb N$ and $A\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$, it holds that
$A$ is diagonalizable (over) $\mathbb C$ if, and only if, there exists a basis $\{v_1, \ldots ,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb C^{n\times 1}$ such that $v_1, \ldots ,v_n$ are all eigenvectors of $A$.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then to find a diagonalizing matrix $P$, you just have to find the vectors $v_1, \ldots ,v_n$ above and define $P$ by letting its columns be the eigenvectors found. This implies that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

This works whether $A$'s eigenvalues have all multiplicty $1$ or not.

Comment: but *distinct eigenvalues* (i.e. all eigenvalues has multiplicity of 1) implies that the eigenvectors corresponding to those eigenvalues are in fact L.I. Thus I do not have check independency by calculating det≠0 or find out by gaussJordan.

Comment: This is true. Your point is? I thought you were asking how to diagonalize a matrix.

Comment: Is this correct?

- I'm given a matrix
- I find out that it is non-normal
- I find its eigenvalues. Let's say I have $m$ of them.
- I find out it does not have distinct eigenvalues
- I find some set of eigenvectors to the eigenvalues, call this set S.
- If and only if dim(span(the eigenvectors)) =  m , I can diagonalize A. (To put the equation in words, just to make sure "If and only if I have as many linearly independent vectors in S, as I have number of eigenvalues, the matrix is diagnoalizable").

Comment: @jacob If I understand you correctly, you got it wrong. The `If and only if dim(span(the eigenvectors)) = m , I can diagonalize A` part is correct if $A$ is a $m\times m$ matrix. But the `If and only if I have as many linearly independent vectors in S, as I have number of eigenvalues, the matrix is diagonalizable` part isn't right. You can have just one eigenvalue in a $3\times 3$ matrix for instance and the matrix can be diagonalizable and you can get three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: So it would be easier to just skip this way of thinking and just stating: find some set of eigenvectors, if they are L.I. and the total # of vectors is p if the matrix is pxp, then you can diagnoalize the matrix.

Comment: @jacob As a practical matter, yes. If in that process you find $p$ L.I. eigenvectors, you can diagonalize it, if you can't find them, you can't diagonalize it.

Answer (score -1):

Is this correct?

- I'm given a matrix
- I find out that it is non-normal
- I find its eigenvalues. Let's say I have m of them.
- I find out it does not have distinct eigenvalues
- I find some set of eigenvectors to the eigenvalues, call this set S.
- If and only if dim(span(the eigenvectors)) =  m , I can diagonalize A. (To put the equation in words, just to make sure "If and only if I have as many linearly independent vectors in S, as I have number of eigenvalues, the matrix is diagnoalizable").

Comment: What is the order of the given matrix? Is it $m\times m$?

Comment: yes it is m x m.

Comment: The last bullet has two *iff's*. The first one is correct, the second is wrong.

Comment: @GitGud ok, got it. maybe.