# When is a matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

The matrix $A$ is diagonalizable with $A=SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $S$ is the matrix with eigenvectors as columns **iff** $A$ has linearly independent eigenvectors.

Correct?

Comment: Slight correction: if $A$ has a set of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, where $A$ is $n \times n$.

Comment: If this is about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713191/diagonalize-a-non-normal-matrix-without-distinct-eigenvalues) question, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I meant "all" eigenvectors are linearly independent. I guess "n" is the same thing as "all" in this case.

Comment: @jacob No, that's wrong, because all eigenvectors can never be L.I. for if $v$ is an eigenvector, so is $\lambda v$, for all $\mathbb F\ni \lambda\neq 0$.

Comment: Wait now... I have $A$, I calulate its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, and for each $\lambda_i$ there is one or more eigenvectors $v_i$, for a total of $n$ eigenvectors. If those $n$ are L.I. then $A$ can be diagonalized. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @jacob, the point is that for each $\lambda_i$, there are *infinitely many* eigenvectors associated with them, but that's because the set of eigenvectors forms a subspace. That subspace is still finite dimensional though.

Comment: @Truth-seek Because this question is nearly 4 years old?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Yeah, my mistake. I don't know what got into me. I just didn't delete that message. Ignore it.